# Chrome Cache-API - caches match

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps, cacheapi

I have cached resources with CacheAddall method with a version say "v22"
with the v22 version there are many files as for example below:

[image: Cache storage]

Now how I can access the same and update or delete individually.
I can access the v22 with

```
caches.keys().then(keys => {
        keys.map(key => {
          console.log(key)
        })
      })
```

but here `console.log` only return `v22`, how how can access for example `/pwa/js/app/js`

I couldn't find a workaround for this.

Answer (score 3):

First you need to install callback as per you version name(ex: v22). So, we need to take the following steps:

1)Open a cache.
 2)Cache our files.
 3)Confirm whether all the required assets are cached or not.

For more clarity you can reach the below urls.
**https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers**

Like below code.

```
var CACHE_NAME = 'my-site-cache-v1';
var urlsToCache = [
  '/',
  '/styles/main.css',
  '/script/main.js'
];

self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  // Perform install steps
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
      .then(function(cache) {
        console.log('Opened cache');
        return cache.addAll(urlsToCache);
      })
  );
});
```

Then for access you need to use `fetch` event of service worker.

Like below code.

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request)
      .then(function(response) {
        // Cache hit - return response
        if (response) {
          return response;
        }
        return fetch(event.request);
      }
    )
  );
});
```

For update and delete you can use `activate` event of service worker. Please read the `cacheWhitelist` properly. But,If you want to update you must be need to change the `chachname/version` name of service worker. For delete you can direct delete using `map()`.

Like below code.

```
self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {

  var cacheWhitelist = [cacheName];

  event.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then(function(cacheNames) {
      return Promise.all(
        cacheNames.map(function(cacheName) {
          if (cacheWhitelist.indexOf(cacheName) === -1) {
            return caches.delete(cacheName);
          }
        })
      );
    })
  );
});
```

I hope it's help you..!!

Comment: whatever code you mentioned, it's already there in my service worker. what I want to achieve is like I have updated certain info in backend(for example notice). I send a notification to service worker with a tag - `update-notices`. my service worker is able to match the tag, but after matching the tag as in my image notices are stored in `/api/notice` the cache key for all the files is V22. Now I wanto delete the `/api/notice` from the cache. How I can do that?

Comment: Joshi, I guess you can't delete specific page inside service-worker. So you need to change the version name then activate event will fire. So, you need to write that code for delete previouse cache. In our project we did same thing.

Comment: I guess it's not good idea to delete..you can update I guess check below urls they mention same..https://love2dev.com/blog/how-to-uninstall-a-service-worker/

Answer (score 0):

I get this to work, but still looking for a better solution.

self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
  console.log("sync event", event);
  var eventData = event.data.json();
  console.log(eventData);

```
    if (eventData.notification.tag === 'notice') {
      var token='';

      var userId = localforage.getItem("userId");
            localforage.getItem("access-token").then(function(value){
                token += value;
               console.log(token);
               console.log(userId);

      var request = new Request("https://myurl/api/notice",{
        "headers": {
          'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + token,
      },
      })

      fetch(request).then(function(response) {
        var rsp = response.clone();
      // cache response for the next time around
       return caches.open(cacheName).then(function (cache) {
         cache.put(request,rsp);
      });
      });
    })    

    }
});
```